# Code folding for LaTeX in Emacs

Tags: emacs, latex, elisp, folding, auctex

Is there an Emacs minor-mode (or piece of elisp code) that lets you selectively hide/show environments while in LaTeX mode? For instance, I would like to move to the beginning of a long `\begin{figure}` block, hit a keystroke, and have the contents of that figure environment hidden from view. Similarly with `\begin{proof}` and so on, and ideally even with `\subsection`s.

Is this possible? I just tried `hs-minor-mode`, `allout-mode`, and `outline-minor-mode`, but most of them don't recognize LaTeX's environments, e.g. hs-minor-mode fails with "scan error: unbalanced parentheses". I would prefer not to have to enter explicit folding marks like {{{ as in [folding-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FoldingMode).

[Ideally it would be great if the folding were [persistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479977/emacs-persistent-folding-mode), but I see that that question doesn't have an accepted answer yet.]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

AUCTeX does folding: http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Folding

> A popular complaint about markup languages like TeX and LaTeX is that there is too much clutter in the source text and that one cannot focus well on the content. There are macros where you are only interested in the content they are enclosing, like font specifiers where the content might already be fontified in a special way by font locking. Or macros the content of which you only want to see when actually editing it, like footnotes or citations. Similarly you might find certain environments or comments distracting when trying to concentrate on the body of your document.
>
> With AUCTeX’s folding functionality you can collapse those items and replace them by a fixed string, the content of one of their arguments, or a mixture of both. If you want to make the original text visible again in order to view or edit it, move point sideways onto the placeholder (also called display string) or left-click with the mouse pointer on it. (The latter is currently only supported on Emacs.) The macro or environment will unfold automatically, stay open as long as point is inside of it and collapse again once you move point out of it. (Note that folding of environments currently does not work in every AUCTeX mode.)
>
> In order to use this feature, you have to activate `TeX-fold-mode` which will activate the auto-reveal feature and the necessary commands to hide and show macros and environments. You can activate the mode in a certain buffer by typing the command `M-x TeX-fold-mode RET` or using the keyboard shortcut `C-c C-o C-f`. If you want to use it every time you edit a LaTeX document, add it to a hook:
>
> ```
> (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda ()
>                              (TeX-fold-mode 1)))
> ```
>
> If it should be activated in all AUCTeX modes, use `TeX-mode-hook` instead of `LaTeX-mode-hook`.
>
> Once the mode is active there are several commands available to hide and show macros, environments and comments...

Comment: You can also use outline commands, like M-x hide-body and M-x show-subtree.  Also check out RefTeX, which has a ToC navigation feature.

Comment: How can I run `TeX-fold-buffer` as well?